# Unity3D: Efficiency of using a queue(list) of IEnumerators, C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What happens and what sort of resources are consumed when you save a reference to an `IEnumerator`, but don't call `StartCoroutine()` on it immediately? ie:

```
IEnumerator myenum;
void Start(){
    myenum = MyIenum(obj);
}

IEnumerator MyIenum(Object obj){
    //Function does it's coroutine stuff
}

//...A while later, in some different function down the road
    StartCoroutine(myenum);
```

Is it bad practice to maintain a queue of `IEnumerators` which you pop off and call `StartCoroutine()` on periodically?

Comment: What is StartCoroutine()?  I suspect this is part of a library that you haven't added as a tag...

Comment: The code or question don't really make sense to me. Could you explain a bit more what you mean and what "stuff" does IEnumerator do? And why does it do stuff and return it?

Comment: I guess performance-wise it will have almost no effect. However I also have hard time understanding IEnumerator. Hope [this article](http://eppz.eu/blog/understanding-ienumerator-in-unity-3d/) can get you somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with it.

They way Unity's Coroutines work is more or less just what you are trying to do.

```
StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());

// ...

IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    // ...
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

does exactly that. First, MyCoroutine() is called, which returns an IEnumerator whose current position is the yielded instance of WaitForEndOfFrame. This enumerator is passed to StartCoroutine(), an engine feature which stores the IEnumerator and, depending on its current position, calls MoveNext() on it when the right moment has come. After MoveNext(), the new current position of the IEnumerator will be the yielded instance of WaitForSeconds, and so on.

If you start several Coroutines, each one has its own IEnumerator, all of which are stored and called MoveNext() upon when their time has come.

So, you can easily write your own Coroutine System, or you can use the one Unity provides. Keeping instances of IEnumerator of course has some memory overhead, as the stack of the yielding function has to be stored somewhere, but apart from that no resources (like CPU) should be used as long as the IEnumerator is not moved.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the right anwser. I don't have a deep IEnumerator knowdge.

Answer (score 1):

I think that won't work. Is not how the Unity3D `StartCoroutine` works.

`StartCoroutine` receives an `IEnumerator` who is the result of your coroutine, and that can be yield. If you just call your function before you passes it to the `StartCoroutine` function, the `StartCoroutine` will do nothing, because your function already been executed.

What I think you should do is save a list of functions, and not a list of enums.

Something like that

```
public delegate IEnumerator YourFunction(Object obj);
public YourFunction savedFunction;

void Start() {
    savedFunction = MyIenum;
}

public IEnumerator MyIenum(Object obj) {
    // Do some stuff
}

public void ExecuteCoroutine() {
    StartCoroutine(savedFunction(new Object));
}
```

And with that you won't have any performance issues, only maybe more memory consumption.

Comment: You in fact are able to store a reference to an `IEnumerator` in a variable and then call `StartCoroutine(IEnumerator i)` on it at a later date.
I've found in nice in some situations as a you can then call `StopCoroutine(IEnumerator i)` if need be to stop a specific instance of a coroutine in case you have several.